# XPath select nodes with attribute names

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose We have a XML document given as

```
<MyDocument>
<Pages>
    <Page>
        <Para>
            <Word show="yes" wo="2">Some</Word>
            <Word>People</Word>
        </Para>
    </Page>
    <Page>
        <Para>
            <Word>Some</Word>
            <Word show="yes">Other</Word>
            <Word show="yes" wo="1">People</Word>
        </Para>
    </Page>
</Pages>
</MyDocument>
```

how can we find all the Word nodes with both attribute 'show' and 'wo'? I tried XPath //*[@show] | //*[@wo] but this expression selects node with @show as well. and //*[@show @wo] is not legal expression.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how can we find all the Word nodes with both attribute 'show' and 'wo'?

Use `and`:

```
//Word[@show and @wo]
```

Or, you can also have multiple conditions in separate square brackets:

```
//Word[@show][@wo]
```